# fast way to convert integer array to byte array (11 bit)

Tags: c#, arrays

I have integer array and I need to convert it to byte array
but I need to take (only and just only) first 11 bit of each element of the هinteger array 
and then convert it to a byte array
I tried this code

```
// ***********convert integer values to byte values
//***********to avoid the left zero padding on the byte array
// *********** first step : convert to binary string 
 // ***********second step : convert binary string to byte array
 // *********** first step
string ByteString = Convert.ToString(IntArray[0], 2).PadLeft(11,'0');
for (int i = 1; i < IntArray.Length; i++)
            ByteString = ByteString + Convert.ToString(IntArray[i], 2).PadLeft(11, '0');



        // ***********second step

        int numOfBytes = ByteString.Length / 8;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(ByteString.Substring(8 * i, 8), 2);

        }
```

But it takes too long time (if the file size large , the code takes more than 1 minute)

I need a very very fast code (very few milliseconds only )
can any one help me ?

Comment: Why do you need fast code?  If you need fast code, why are you using C#?

Comment: please tell me how you plan to store only the least significant 11 bits of a 16 bit integer in an 8 bit byte? After this I can show you how to use the `&` operator to mask off those 11 bits as theyre being stored in the byte (I just need help with the part where we fit a quart into a pint pot) to avoid all this string conversion malarkey, which is incredibly slow and resource intensive

Comment: I used c# because it produce a useful librarys for me  , and I need a fast code because I need it in encryption process (must be very fast)

Comment: @CaiusJard I have int values (0-1023) , and i have to convert the values to (0-255) byte array  only, I can not manipulate (play) with the values , if you have another way please tell me about it.

Comment: @ErikPhilips C# isn't particularly slow - not sure that comment is helpful

Comment: i don't think you understood me. I think you're trying to store 11 bits of information in an 8 bit byte. Am I correct? How do you plan to do this? How will you completely pour a 750ml bottle of wine into a half litre glass, without spilling any?

Comment: Doing this work *via strings* is a terrible idea. If you need to deal with bits: then C# supports all the usual bitwise operators you should need - masks, shifts, etc. What you actually *want to do* (inputs and outputs) is still very unclear to me, though.

Comment: @CaiusJard as I understand it: the 3 bits left over would be the first three bits of the next chunk - then it would be a 5/6 split, then a 2/8/1, etc. The *endianness* could do with clarification, of course

Comment: @CaiusJard the first element in the byte array will take the first 8 bit from the first element of the integer array , the second element in the byte array will take the bits (9-11) from the first element on the integer array and (1-5) bit from the second element  on the integer array , I hope you will anderstand what I mean !

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for your advise , please read  my last comment before this comment

Comment: @MarcGravell exactly !

Comment: @MSc What you are trying to do, basically ignoring byte boundaries in your target data, is rather tricky.  Even in C++.  In C#, it's trickier imo.  I'd make use of the 11bits into two-bytes answer below, or google 'C# bitstream' or check out Cap'n Proto or a compression library.  This is not a wheel you want to reinvent unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: It's not that difficult. Instead of string, use [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're going to be doing a lot of shifting and masking. The exact nature of that depends on the layout you want. If we assume that we pack little-endian from each int, appending *on the left*, so two 11-bit integers with positions:

```
abcdefghijk lmnopqrstuv
```

become the 8-bit chunks:

```
defghijk  rstuvabc 00lmnopq
```

(i.e. take the lowest 8 bits of the first integer, which leaves 3 left over, so pack those into the low 3 bits of the next byte, then take the lowest 5 bits of the second integer, then finally the remaining 6 bits, padding with zero), then something like this should work:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

static class Program
{
    static string AsBinary(int val) => Convert.ToString(val, 2).PadLeft(11, '0');
    static string AsBinary(byte val) => Convert.ToString(val, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] source = new int[1432];
        var rand = new Random(123456);
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            source[i] = rand.Next(0, 2047); // 11 bits

        // Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", source.Take(5).Select(AsBinary)));


        var raw = Encode(source);
        // Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", raw.Take(6).Select(AsBinary)));
        var clone = Decode(raw);

        // now prove that it worked OK
        if (source.Length != clone.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Length: {source.Length} vs {clone.Length}");
        }
        else
        {
            int failCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (source[i] != clone[i] && failCount++ == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {source[i]} vs {clone[i]}");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Errors: {failCount}");
        }
    }
    static byte[] Encode(int[] source)
    {
        long bits = source.Length * 11;
        int len = (int)(bits / 8);
        if ((bits % 8) != 0) len++;

        byte[] arr = new byte[len];
        int bitOffset = 0, index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            // note: this encodes little-endian
            int val = source[i] & 2047;
            int bitsLeft = 11;
            if(bitOffset != 0)
            {
                val = val << bitOffset;
                arr[index++] |= (byte)val;
                bitsLeft -= (8 - bitOffset);
                val >>= 8;
            }

            if(bitsLeft >= 8)
            {
                arr[index++] = (byte)val;
                bitsLeft -= 8;
                val >>= 8;
            }
            if(bitsLeft != 0)
            {
                arr[index] = (byte)val;
            }
            bitOffset = bitsLeft;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    private static int[] Decode(byte[] source)
    {
        int bits = source.Length * 8;
        int len = (int)(bits / 11);
        // note no need to worry about remaining chunks - no ambiguity since 11 > 8

        int[] arr = new int[len];
        int bitOffset = 0, index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            int val = source[i] << bitOffset;
            int bitsLeftInVal = 11 - bitOffset;
            if(bitsLeftInVal > 8)
            {
                arr[index] |= val;
                bitOffset += 8;
            }
            else if(bitsLeftInVal == 8)
            {
                arr[index++] |= val;
                bitOffset = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[index++] |= (val & 2047);
                if(index != arr.Length) arr[index] = val >> 11;
                bitOffset = 8 - bitsLeftInVal;
            }
        }
        return arr;

    }
}
```

If you need a different layout you'll need to tweak it.

This encodes 512 MiB in just over a second on my machine.

---

Overview to the `Encode` method:

The first thing is does is pre-calculate the amount of space that is going to be required, and allocate the output buffer; since each input contributes 11 bits to the output, this is just some modulo math:

```
    long bits = source.Length * 11;
    int len = (int)(bits / 8);
    if ((bits % 8) != 0) len++;

    byte[] arr = new byte[len];
```

We know the output position won't match the input, and we know we're going to be starting each 11-bit chunk at different positions in bytes each time, so allocate variables for those, and loop over the input:

```
    int bitOffset = 0, index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        ...
    }
    return arr;
```

So: taking each input in turn (where the input is the value at position `i`), take the low 11 bits of the value - and observe that we have 11 bits (of this value) still to write:

```
        int val = source[i] & 2047;
        int bitsLeft = 11;
```

Now, if the current **output** value is *partially written* (i.e. `bitOffset != 0`), we should deal with that first. The amount of space left in the current **output** is `8 - bitOffset`. Since we always have 11 input bits we don't need to worry about having more space than values to fill, so: left-shift our value by `bitOffset` (pads on the right with `bitOffset` zeros, as a binary operation), and "or" the lowest 8 bits of this with the output byte. Essentially this says "if `bitOffset` is 3, write the 5 low bits of `val` into the 5 high bits of the output buffer"; finally, fixup the values: increment our write position, record that we have fewer bits of the current value still to write, and use right-shift to discard the 8 low bits of `val` (which is made of `bitOffset` zeros and `8 - bitOffset` "real" bits):

```
        if(bitOffset != 0)
        {
            val = val << bitOffset;
            arr[index++] |= (byte)val;
            bitsLeft -= (8 - bitOffset);
            val >>= 8;
        }
```

The next question is: do we have (at least) an entire byte of data left? We might not, if `bitOffset` was 1 for example (so we'll have written 7 bits already, leaving just 4). If we *do*, we can just stamp that down and increment the write position - then once again track how many are left and throw away the low 8 bits:

```
        if(bitsLeft >= 8)
        {
            arr[index++] = (byte)val;
            bitsLeft -= 8;
            val >>= 8;
        }
```

And it is *possible* that we've still got some left-over; for example, if `bitOffset` was 7 we'll have written 1 bit in the first chunk, 8 bits in the second, leaving 2 more to write - or if `bitOffset` was 0 we won't have written anything in the first chunk, 8 in the second, leaving 3 left to write. So, stamp down whatever is left, but **do not** increment the write position - we've written to the low bits, but the next value might need to write to the high bits. Finally, update `bitOffset` to be *however many low bits we wrote in the last step* (which could be zero):

```
        if(bitsLeft != 0)
        {
            arr[index] = (byte)val;
        }
        bitOffset = bitsLeft;
```

The `Decode` operation is the reverse of this logic - again, calculate the sizes and prepare the state:

```
    int bits = source.Length * 8;
    int len = (int)(bits / 11);

    int[] arr = new int[len];
    int bitOffset = 0, index = 0;
```

Now loop over the input:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        ...
    }
    return arr;
```

Now, `bitOffset` is the start position that we want to write to *in the current 11-bit value*, so if we start at the start, it will be 0 on the first byte, then 8; 3 bits of the second byte join with the first 11-bit integer, so the 5 bits become part of the second - so `bitOffset` is 5 on the 3rd byte, etc. We can calculate the number of bits left *in the current integer* by subtracting from 11:

```
        int val = source[i] << bitOffset;
        int bitsLeftInVal = 11 - bitOffset;
```

Now we have 3 possible scenarios:

1) if we have **more** than 8 bits left in the current value, we can stamp down our input (as a bitwise "or") but *do not* increment the write position (as we have more to write for this value), and note that we're 8-bits further along:

```
        if(bitsLeftInVal > 8)
        {
            arr[index] |= val;
            bitOffset += 8;
        }
```

2) if we have **exactly** 8 bits left in the current value, we can stamp down our input (as a bitwise "or") *and* increment the write position; the next loop can start at zero:

```
        else if(bitsLeftInVal == 8)
        {
            arr[index++] |= val;
            bitOffset = 0;
        }
```

3) otherwise, we have *less than* 8 bits left in the current value; so we need to write the first `bitsLeftInVal` bits to the current output position (incrementing the output position), and whatever is left to the *next* output position. Since we already left-shifted by `bitOffset`, what this really means is simply: stamp down (as a bitwise "or") the low 11 bits (`val & 2047`) to the current position, and whatever is left (`val >> 11`) to the next **if** that wouldn't exceed our output buffer (padding zeros). Then calculate our new `bitOffset`:

```
        else
        {
            arr[index++] |= (val & 2047);
            if(index != arr.Length) arr[index] = val >> 11;
            bitOffset = 8 - bitsLeftInVal;
        }
```

And that's basically it. Lots of bitwise operations - shifts (`<<` / `>>`), masks (`&`) and combinations (`|`).

Comment: This code is what I really need, but it still a bit complicated to me, can you please explain the important parts for me?? And does the “decode function “ return the original int data?

Comment: @MSc "And does the 'decode' function “ return the original int data?" - yes, and there's a loop that shows this against random data; I'm going to need to get a coffee to write an explanation, though... give me a minute

Comment: OK,waiting for you.

Comment: @MSc try now; note, however, that I can't do a full tutorial on binary arithmetic...

Comment: Thank you very much, I will not forget your help, but there is a little problem with the last element in the "decode function" compiler shows "{"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}"...... I tried to fixed it but I failed :'(

Comment: the problem appears here :    else
            {
                arr[index++] |= (val & 2047);
                arr[index] = val >> 11; //here 
                bitOffset = 8 - bitsLeftInVal;
            }
        }

Comment: @MSc possibly an edge case that affects some lengths and not others, so I would *assume* it relates to the 3rd (`else`) scenario, and in particular the second write (`arr[index] = ...`); what is the length you're using?

Comment: @MSc hmmm; `len` is correct for that - one moment while I debug

Comment: @MSc yeah, this happens when there are spare padding zeros in the input; it is unambiguous that we should round down, so just change that line to `if(index != arr.Length) arr[index] = val >> 11;`

Comment: Note that I didn't use the part (if-else ) in the main program because it's illegal to (decode ) the encrypted data at the encryption process (and that is what I am doing)

Comment: @MSc minor point: this isn't encryption in any way - let's be very very clear on that

Comment: My whole project is encryption and decryption processes (this is a little part to convert my final values to a byte array only[without loss of data or enlarge it too much(take what I need only)] ) .

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to store the least significant 11 bits of an int into two bytes such that the least significant byte has bits 1-8 inclusive and the most significant byte has 9-11:

```
int toStore = 123456789;
byte msb = (byte) ((toStore >> 8) & 7); //or 0b111
byte lsb = (byte) (toStore & 255); //or 0b11111111
```

To check this, 123456789 in binary is:

```
0b111010110111100110100010101
                  MMMLLLLLLLL
```

The bits above L are lsb, and have a value of 21, above M are msb and have a value of 5

Doing the work is the shift operator >> where all the binary digits are slid to the right 8 places (8 of them disappear from the right hand side - they're gone, into oblivion):

```
0b111010110111100110100010101 >> 8 =
        0b1110101101111001101
```

And the mask operator & (the mask operator works by only keeping bits where, in each position, they're 1 in the value and also 1 in the mask) :

```
0b111010110111100110100010101 &
0b000000000000000000011111111 (255) =
0b000000000000000000000010101
```

If you're processing an int array, just do this in a loop:

```
byte[] bs = new byte[ intarray.Length*2 ];
for(int x = 0, b=0; x < intarray.Length; x++){
  int toStore = intarray[x];
  bs[b++] = (byte) ((toStore >> 8) & 7);
  bs[b++] = (byte) (toStore & 255);
}
```

Comment: my integer array length is unknown , it may be thousands of elements, and can you please explain the code for me ?!

Comment: can you please edit the code to conclude any length of integer array? and explain the code for me :(

Comment: ive put an example in as to how you would apply this technique to a whole array of int. I was kinda hoping you'd do that part for yourself, as a bit of a learning exercise though. I don't think the loop bit is so significantly different to the first bit that it needs an explanation of its own, but if you're struggling with understanding it, left me know

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&7` for 3 bits instead of `&15`?  Also I think C# now supports declaring like "0b0111"

Comment: this error appears: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: I've changed the bracketing to assist with that

Comment: Unfortunately I am struggling with understanding it ! :( <<<< don't say "stupid" please ! I am still a student

Comment: Understanding what?

Comment: I can not understood these steps :  bs[b++] = (byte) ((toStore >> 8) & 7);
  bs[b++] = (byte) (toStore & 255);

Comment: bs is a byte array, b is an index, ++ increments the index after it has been used, toStore is your int that you're wanting 11 bits from, >>8&7 gets bits 9-11, &255 gets bits 1-8. I covered some of this in my post but if you really want to know a lot about bit shift operator and bit mask operator, read a blog or book dedicated to it.. there's too much to talk about to make it fit within the scope of a stack overflow answer; I love teaching, but my mission is not to replace your lecturer

Comment: You should be able to work this one out yourself. Shift your most significant byte left 8 bits `<<8` then OR it with the least significant byte using `|`. I'm not here to do your homework for you, nor did you ever ask about the reverse operation in the original question. When you graduate and move into industry you too will find "scope creep" to be a troublesome and irritating thing; try not to do it to fellow professionals

Comment: Doing an MSc without any lecturers must indeed be an uphill battle. You should find the person who collected your tuition fees and wring their neck